# How can I clone a mercurial repo including subrepos over http without having to be authenticated for every repo?

Tags: apache, http, authentication, mercurial, clone

It would be preferable to be authenticated only once.

Comment: have you tried putting the authentication in the url like this: http://user:pass@url.com/repo/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify it when you clone: `http://user:pass@url.com/repo/`

or you can put it in your global `.hgrc` file (note your password is in plain text)

Comment: Is it not so that the .hgrc file will only be used for pulling and pushing?

Comment: The global .hgrc from your home directory can specify the userid and since its the same as whats in the repos i don't see why a password wouldn't work as well.
http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-the-basics.html
Search for "home directory" and it you can see about the global hgrc

Comment: OK, the .hgrc works. On Windows the home directory is normally C:\Users\Username.